# I want my events to active a especific tab when clicked (using idTabs and clndr.js for the calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tabs

[image]

I have 3 tabs on the right and a calendar on the left. When clicked a number (event) of the calendar i want this to activate the tab3. idTabs doesn't seem to have methods to activate a tab, but I know we can trigger it manually, but don't know how, I'm a begginer in js.
This is the code I already have that gives me the information of the events in that especific tab3.

### My js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {



    $('#calendar').clndr({
        template: $('#calendar-template').html(),
        events: [
     { date: '2015-04-09', title: 'CLNDR GitHub Page Finished', url: 'http://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR' },
     { date: '2015-04-19', title: 'CLNDR GitHub Page Finished', url: 'http://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR' },
     { date: '2015-04-19', title: 'Event 2', url: 'http://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR' },
     { date: '2015-04-19', title: 'Event 3', url: 'http://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR' },
     { date: '2015-04-25', title: 'CLNDR GitHub Page Finished', url: 'http://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR' }
  ],

        clickEvents: {
            click: function (target) {
                console.log(target);
                var output = "";
                for (i = 0; i < target.events.length; i++) {
                    output += " -> " + target.events[i].title + " <br /> ";
                }
                //alert("Events for day: " + target.date.toString() + " \n " + output);
                document.getElementById("tab3").innerHTML = "Events for day: " + target.date.toString() + " <br /> " + output;

            },
            onMonthChange: function (month) {
                console.log('you just went to ' + month.format('MMMM, YYYY'));
            }
        },
        doneRendering: function () {
            console.log('this would be a fine place to attach custom event handlers.');
        }
    });
```

### My html

```
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 MFCBlock"  id="tabsIndice">
                <ul class="menu_indice idTabs">
                     <li><a href="#tab1">Categorias</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#tab2">Comentários</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#tab3" id="tab_3">Eventos</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="menufull" id="tab1">
                    <ul class="categorias_list left_cat tabs" style="list-style:none;">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="categorias_list right_cat tabs">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="menufull" id="tab2">
                    <ul class="categorias_list left_cat tabs" style="list-style:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">City Tours & Sightseeing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">City Pass & Skip the Line Tickets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Turisticos e seguir a excursão no ônibus seguinte</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tour Noturnos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cruzeiros com jantar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    <div class="menufull" id="tab3">
                        <ul class="categorias_list left_cat tabs" style="list-style:none;">
                            <li><a href="#">City Tours & Sightseeing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">City Pass & Skip the Line Tickets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turisticos e seguir a excursão no ônibus seguinte</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tours de Segway e de Caminhada</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Viagens de um dia & Excursões para fora da cidade</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="categorias_list right_cat tabs">
                            <li><a href="#">Tour Noturnos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cruzeiros com jantar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate any help.